# failed to create a R data frame using text data to fill different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am reading some data from a text file and then extracting certain sentences from it. finally, I am trying to populate a dataframe using the objects created and using for loop for that.

I have tried writing a loop for that:

```
 us_doc1 <- "This is a sample text which has lots of bla bla bla text data. Employee Handbook 2019. docx Page 1."

    us_doc2 <- "This is another sample text which has lots of bla bla bla text data. Employee Handbook 2019. docx Page 2."

    us_docx <- unlist(list(us_doc1, us_doc2))

    usDoc <- data.frame()

    len <- length(us_doc)

    for (i in 1:len) {
     # read every page
     x <- us_doc[i]

     # remove white spaces from the text
     x <- gsub("\\s+", " ", x)

     # grep sentence
     x <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\\."))
     PageRefrence <- x[grep(pattern = "docx Page", x, ignore.case = T)]
  handbook <- x[grep(pattern = "Employee Handbook 2019.docx", x, ignore.case = T)]

     usDoc <- rbind(i, handbook, PageRefrence, x, usDoc)

    }



expected a data frame:

    v1    v2                            v3                  v4
    1     Employee Handbook 2019.docx   docx Page 1         This is a.....
    2     Employee Handbook 2019.docx   docx Page 2         This is another...
```

Comment: Have you considered using the nlp packages for R? This type of thing is quite inefficient.  Repeatedly `rbind`ing will make copies, also it is good practice to use `TRUE` instead of `T` as `T` can be assigned to anything.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi no I have not considered any package, because of certain limitations that I am restricted to. but may be you let me know some reference so that I could review. thank you.

Comment: not much of an R user these days, but the CRAN task views, eg. https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html, are excellent resources for finding packages related to subjects